# Webpack, babel and React Error message

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

Out of nowhere I started getting this error message,

> Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a
>   configuration object that does not match the API schema.
>    - configuration has an unknown property 'devserver'. These properties are valid:    object { amd?, bail?, cache?, context?, dependencies?,
>   devServer?, devtool?, entry, externals?, loader?, module?, name?,
>   node?, output?, performance?, plugins?, profile?, recordsInputPath?,
>   recordsOutputPath?, recordsPath?, resolve?, resolveLoader?, stats?,
>   target?, watch?, watchOptions? }    For typos: please correct them.
>   For loader options: webpack 2 no longer allows custom properties in
>   configuration.
>        Loaders should be updated to allow passing options via loader options in module.rules.
>        Until loaders are updated one can use the LoaderOptionsPlugin to pass these options to the loader:
>        plugins: [
>          new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
>            // test: /.xxx$/, // may apply this only for some modules
>            options: {
>              devserver: ...
>            }
>          })
>        ]

I have been scouring the internet for the past 2 hours trying to find a solution but I am going round in circles!

Here is my .babelrc, webpack.config.js, .js and package.json files.

Any help would be amazing. Thanks

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets":[
    "react",
    ["es2015", {"modules": false, "loose": true}]
  ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "complete-intro-to-react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A two day workshop on a complete intro to React",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Brian Holt <btholt@gmail.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test jest",
    "update-test": "npm run test -- -u",
    "build": "webpack",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server",
    "lint": "eslint js/**/*.js webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "webpack --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "0.15.2",
    "express": "4.14.0",
    "history": "^4.4.0",
    "lodash": "4.16.2",
    "preact": "^6.4.0",
    "preact-compat": "^3.9.3",
    "react": "15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "15.3.2",
    "react-redux": "4.4.0",
    "react-router": "4.0.0-alpha.5",
    "redux": "3.3.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-jest": "16.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.7",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2017": "6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-register": "6.16.0",
    "css-loader": "0.25.0",
    "enzyme": "2.0.0",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^1.3.0",
    "eslint": "3.6.1",
    "eslint-config-standard": "6.1.0",
    "eslint-config-standard-jsx": "3.1.0",
    "eslint-config-standard-react": "4.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "1.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "2.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "6.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "2.0.0",
    "jest": "15.1.1",
    "jsdom": "9.5.0",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "15.3.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.3.2",
    "style-loader": "0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^2.1.0-beta.22",
    "webpack-dev-server": "1.16.2"
  },
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/btholt/complete-intro-to-react.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "workshop",
    "intro",
    "redux"
  ],
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/btholt/complete-intro-to-react/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/btholt/complete-intro-to-react#readme"
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: './js/ClientApp.js',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devserver: {
    publicPath: '/public/'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.json']
  },
  stats: {
    colors: true,
    reasons: true,
    chunks: false
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              url: true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and the .js file

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'

import '../public/normalize.css'
import '../public/style.css'

const App = React.createClass({
  render () {
    return (
            <div className='app'>
                <div className="landing">
                    <h1>svideo</h1>
                    <input type="text" placeholder='search' />
                    <a>or Browse All</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
})

render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the devserver object it complains about?

Comment: Hi @cbll it works properly then. I am following along with a course on React and web pack so I am trying to stay on track with the course. And it is showing that this should work fine is all.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `devServer` as error message suggests?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I feel soooo stupid! Thank you so much! Wow...just wow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capital "S"  -->`devServer` not `devserver`!